# Multiple File Upload in codeigniter using HTML5 and XHR

Tags: html, codeigniter, xmlhttprequest

I'm working on multifile upload using html5 and xhr, as you can see I'm sending requests in loop which is a bad 
concept but I'm not able to upload files when I send it outside the loop and only the last file gets upoaded. 
Where am I going wrong?

```
$('#uploadimg').on('click', function(e) {

    var files = document.getElementById('files').files;

    var formData = new FormData();
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        formData.append('file', files[i]);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost/ajaxuploader/upload/uploadimg');
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                console.log('all done: ' + xhr.status);
            } else {
                console.log('Something went terribly wrong...');
            }
        };

        xhr.send(formData);

    }

    // now post a new XHR request
});
```

Codeigniter

```
public function uploadimg (){

    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'uploads/' ;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|doc';

    $config['remove_spaces'] = 'TRUE';

    $this -> load -> library('upload', $config);
    //$this->upload->initialize($config);

    foreach ($_FILES as $k => $f) :
        $this -> upload -> do_upload($k);
    endforeach;
    //$this->index();
}
```

Comment: a quick 10 second google search returned: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/jQuery-File-Upload,---Multi-file-upload-with-CodeIgniter

Comment: @Mike: That's helpful, but it looks like the OP needs help with *this* code (and doesn't appear to be using jQuery). Your tone just sounds a bit dismissive.

Comment: i already googled enough and came across all options, the code in the above link does not work, thats y i opted to code myself..  i know i m making a mistake in codeigniter, can anyone clear it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its seems the first thing you should look at is your js for loop.  ID's should be unique so I would rule that approach out.

I would maybe loop each input field, check to see if the attr type == file, then append that to your formData object.

```
var inpts    = document.getElementsByTagName('input');      

    for(var i=0; i < inpts.length; i++)
    {
       if(inpts[i].getAttribute('type') == 'file')
       {
           formData.append('myFiles[]', inpts[i].files[0]);
       }
    }
```

On the server side I would look at your foreach loop, maybe a for loop might suffice.

```
for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES); $i++){
   $this->upload->initialize(); //new initialization for each file
   $this->upload->do_upload($_FILES[$i]);
   continue;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys i figured out the problem codeigniter is working fine, the problem is in the jquery.  this is the line causing the problem.  "formData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);" Thanks for all for takign efforts to solve my issue

```
$('#uploadimg').on('click', function(e) {
            //console.log(files);
            //               files = document.getElementById('files').files;
            var formData = new FormData();
            $(files).each(function(i) {
                formData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
            })
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost/ajaxuploader/upload/uploadimg');
            xhr.onload = function(data) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            };

            xhr.send(formData);
        });
```